# Device is not compatible with this version in GooglePlay Store

Tags: android, xml

I have tested my application on three different android devices, I downloaded release apk before put it in the google play store and it worked.

I have put on the google play store and the application has just published on Google play store. However, when I attempt to download the app, it shows the following message

> your device is not compatible with this version

Not only on my device, I asked couple of my friend to test the app, everybody gets the same message. And it is also listed supported device is 0 in the google play store.

I have the following `AndroidManifesto` and `buildgradle`.

**AndroidManifesto.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.xxx.xxx">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
        android:required="true" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.xxx.xxx.xxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.xxxx.xxxx.xxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- [END gcm_receiver] -->
        <!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
        <service
            android:name=".MyGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->
        <!-- [START instanceId_listener] -->
        <service
            android:name=".MyInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END instanceId_listener] -->
        <service
            android:name=".RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false" />
</manifest>
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxxx'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':chat-message-view')
    provided 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
```